# PHP Convert number to currency

Tags: php, numbers, currency

I've had a good look around for any help with my problem so hopefully someone can help me here.

Basically i have a number which is saved into a $price, the number is 15900. Which should translate to 159.00.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What happens with `15931`, is it `159.31`, too?

Comment: Leave it as `15900` and treat it as cents rather than dollars. In Zimbabwe, treat is as mega-Z$ rather than giga-Z$.

Comment: Is it also possible to show the 00 in the number? for example 159.00 or 164.78

Comment: Do you want just the two digits from the right to be treated as cents/fraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) for this. It will return a string, thereby keeping the decimal places intact, even if they will be `.00`.

```
$price = 15900;

// Defaults to a comma as a thousands separator
// but I've set it to an empty string (last argument)
$formatted = number_format( $price / 100, 2, '.', '' );

echo $formatted;
```

Or better still, maybe have a look at [`money_format`](http://php.net/money_format) as well, depending on whether internationalized notations and/or currency symbols are of importance as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$current = 15900;
$your = round($current / 100, 2);
```